# Trying to understand ASP.Net Membership, Users, and Logging in

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I'm building my first ASP.Net web application. I've gotten pretty far, but I'm confused about the built-in account features.

I created my own database, got it set up using the aspnet_regsql tool, set up the membership and role providers in web.config, and everything seems to be working great. I can create new accounts, log in, etc. In trying to add roles, I found a lot of older articles and I think I've got a confusing mix of new and old information now.

Basically, I am trying to get a list of user accounts so I can edit them and assign roles. It seems that `Membership.GetAllUsers` looks in the table called aspnet_Users, but the login accounts are in AspNetUsers. As a result, GetAllUsers returns nothing.

After a couple hours of internet searching, I'm still not sure what to do. How can I use the built-in tools to set up user roles, so I can restrict access to certain pages?

EDIT: I finally found some documentation on the ApplicationUserManager and RoleManager for the Owin identity framework. So I think I'm on the right track, but I'm still stuck simply trying to get a list of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! Lists of users and roles in the new ASP.Net Identity Framework (version 2.0) can be accessed like this, and the data is stored in the AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles tables.

```
Protected Sub BindUsersToUserList()
    Dim manager As New UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)(New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(New ApplicationDbContext))
    UserList.DataSource = manager.Users.ToList
    UserList.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub BindRolesToList()
    Dim rm As New RoleManager(Of IdentityRole)(New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole)(New ApplicationDbContext))
    UsersRoleList.DataSource = rm.Roles.Select(Function(q) q.Name).ToList
    UsersRoleList.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: I also figured out how to modify the Site.Master navbar/menu by user roles, and restrict access to pages and controls as well. Looks like I'm all set.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on it last week aswell and...
First of all you have to create in a table UserRole row, for example READ and WRITE. Then in User Session you have to check this role of current user. 
 if Session["USER"] = "READ" then change viewstate or disable the possible buttons to edit, add, delete etc. 
 Hope I understood you correctly. And I did it with c#, but I think vb.net has the same way.